# NSArray Sorting

Tags: sorting, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` with values that I am pulling from an `NSDictionary` using a selector to sort with which has the following values:

1. John
2. Brian
3. Alex
   ....
4. Dave

When I use the code below, since they are being compared as strings, the list comes back with:

```c
NSArray *array = [[[self myDictionary] allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

1. John
2. Dave
3. Brian
   ...

How can I get these values to sort correctly where they are in order 1, 2, 3, etc.?  I've looked at several different examples for sorting, but have not been able to find an example like mine.  I must also mention that I'm new to objective-c and iOS.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to figure out the solution.  I created an `NSComparisonResult` block using custom logic to read the number portion off of the front of each string and then comparing them numerically:

```
NSComparisonResult (^sortByNumber)(id, id) = ^(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    //Convert items to strings
    NSString *s1 = (NSString *)obj1;
    NSString *s2 = (NSString *)obj2;

    //Find the period and grab the number
    NSUInteger periodLoc1 = [s1 rangeOfString:@"."].location;
    NSString *number1 = [s1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, periodLoc1)];

    NSUInteger periodLoc2 = [s2 rangeOfString:@"."].location;
    NSString *number2 = [s2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, periodLoc2)];

    //Compare the numeric values of the numbers
    return [number1 compare:number2 options:NSNumericSearch];
};
```

Then I sort my array by calling:

```
NSArray *array = [[[self myDictionary] allValues] sortedArrayUsingComparator:sortByNumber];
```